# Read txt file and pick out sections using php and save each section to the database

Tags: php, fgets

Say this is my text file, line by line is a section of information split by *

```
ID 1*100042176*472**any info**5030*6*1 PA1*101*90*101******

ID 1=ID101 = ID102 = ID103 = and so on
```

So I want to be able to read this information and translate

```
    ID101=1000042176 
    ID102=472 
    ID103= 
    ID104=any info
    ID105= 
    ID106=5030
    ID107=6 ID108=1
    PA101=101 PA102=90 PA103=101 etc.
```

Each piece of info relates to a table entry

I can read the file line by line but cant work out how to pick out each line and then pick out between the *

any help would be appreciated.

```
<?PHP
function readCSV($csvFile){
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text[\n] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;
}


// Set path to CSV file
$csvFile = 'merchant.txt';

$csv = readCSV($csvFile);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($csv);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: I see that sometimes your delimiter which is * is repeated, is it right. Does ID101=...etc is part of the file?

Comment: If you are going to show us the foramt of an input file that need bits picking out of it, PLEASE show it exactly, do not summarise

Comment: DXS*9252131001*VA*V1/6*1 ¬
ST*001*0001¬
BA1*ITL000003443697*NV90 373 000*0323**¬
CA1*MEISP3415      *CF7900MDB   *0127**`¬
CA2*3647645*45196*3647645*45196¬
CA3*5190952*2955412*1525540*7100*5190952*2955412*1525540*7100*710000*710000*0*0¬
CA4*1493730*9025*1493730*9025*0*0*0*0*0*0¬
CA7*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0¬
CA8*10841*10841¬
CA10*1030*1030*0*0¬
CA15*10420*1*66*16*79*73*47*0*0*0¬
CA15*10420*2*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0¬
CA22*0¬
CB1*CMS100042176*472*10.8.7**¬
DA1*MEI26990271979 *ADV5300     *0430**¬
     ¬NEW LINE¬  THERE ARE MORE LINES AND THEY ALSO HAVE A DIFFERENT AMOUNT OF DATA ON EACH LINE

Answer (score 0):

Part of this depends on how literal your example, but you can generally do this with `explode()` along with a regular expression. For instance, this pattern will match what you've provided which you can [test online](https://regex101.com/r/aJODrs/2).

`/^ID (?<G1_ID>\d+)(?<G1>(\*[^*]*)+) PA(?<G2_ID>\d+)(?<G2>(\*[^*]*)+)$/`

Once you test the pattern your match array will hold a bunch of named values that you can further `explode()` using `*` as a delimiter.

Below is a working example that puts everything into the `$final` array.

```php
$test = 'ID 1*100042176*472**any info**5030*6*1 PA1*101*90*101******';
$pattern = '/^ID (?<G1_ID>\d+)(?<G1>(\*[^*]*)+) PA(?<G2_ID>\d+)(?<G2>(\*[^*]*)+)$/';

if (!preg_match($pattern, $test, $matches)) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Not matched');
}

$group_1_id = $matches['G1_ID'];
$group_2_id = $matches['G2_ID'];

$group_1_parts = explode('*', $matches['G1']);
$group_2_parts = explode('*', $matches['G2']);

if (count($group_1_parts) < 2) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Group 1 does not have enough asterisks');
}

if (count($group_2_parts) < 2) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Group 2 does not have enough asterisks');
}

$final = [];
for ($i = 1; $i < count($group_1_parts); $i++) {
    $i_padded = str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $final[] = "ID${group_1_id}${i_padded}=${group_1_parts[$i]}";
}

for ($i = 1; $i < count($group_2_parts); $i++) {
    $i_padded = str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $final[] = "PA${group_1_id}${i_padded}=${group_2_parts[$i]}";
}


print_r(array_values($final));
```